# Tensorflow - ImportError: Could not find 'msvcp140.dll'

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, pip

I am just a beginner to a tensorflow and trying to install TensorFlow with CPU support only.

Initially, I downloaded and installed Python 3.5.2 version from https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-352/

After successful installation, I ran the command `pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow` which installed tensorflow-1.8.0.

To test installation i just ran following commands:

```
> python

> import tensorflow as tf
```

But this gave me an **error**:

> ImportError: Could not find 'msvcp140.dll'. TensorFlow requires that
>   this DLL be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH%
>   environment variable. You may install this DLL by downloading Visual
>   C++ 2015 Redistributable Update 3 from this URL:
>   https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53587

I searched for this issue and found link to an issue https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17393.

According to above i tried running command

```
pip install tensorflow==1.5
```

But, this didn't solved my problem.

I even tried downloading ***msvcp140.dll*** and manually coping it under ***C:\Windows\SysWOW64*** folder and reinstalling python and tensorflow.

How do I fix this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied ***msvcp140.dll*** to path ***C:\Users\PCName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35***
and it worked for me.

I also switched back to tensorflow 1.8 from 1.5.

Answer (score 1):

download msvcp140.dll or click  https://www.dll-files.com/msvcp140.dll.html

find your python path
path will find easy from your error

error will show like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Users\sky network\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import *
File "C:\Users\sky network\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
File "C:\Users\sky network\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 30, in <module>
self_check.preload_check()
File "C:\Users\sky network\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
packages\tensorflow\python\platform\self_check.py", line 55, in preload_check
% build_info.msvcp_dll_name)
```

from my error the python path is

"File "C:\Users\sky network\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36"

if u cant find the AppData folder

click folder view option and enable hidden files

paste the file "msvcp140.dll" into

C:\Users\sky network\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36

Comment: This is the way!

Answer (score 0):

You can download the package from the url https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53587 and install it. This will solve the issue.

Comment: check the second option and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: It worked for me. Thanks a lot. I don't know why people gave you downvotes but you really saved me.  :)